# An interesting eight pieces Queen endgame

Tags: analysis, endgame, queen-endgame

Looking at a human game between strong players, one of the variations reached the following endgame WHITE to move.

```
[FEN "4Q3/8/2pK4/1p6/1P4k1/P7/8/7q w - - 0 1"]
```

Since Qxc6 is a draw (Lomonosov tablebases) is the endgame a draw? Or there is a sophisticated win for White in some way, maybe submitting the black King to a barrage of checks? Since my engine does NOT have tablebases incorporated into it I am in the complete dark. What does FinalGen say about this endgame?

Comment: It is becoming a useless question since the above position is derivate by the following WHITE King in d4 Bishop in e4 pawns in a3 b4 f3 BLACK King in h5 Bishop in d5 pawns in b5 c6 h6. My computer (Houdini 6.02) plays Ke5 , leading to the position above. However , if you manually play Bxd5 cxd5 after a while Houdini discover the pawn sacrifice a4!! with a position completely winning for White. The curiosity remain , however.

Answer (score 2):

Stockfish with tablebases gives flat 0.00 so it seems highly likely to be a draw. A problem for White is they can't even take the c6 pawn with the king, 1.Kc7 Qh2+ 2.Kxc6 is a draw. So since Black can just keep giving checks and force the white king on awkward squares this seems hard to ever be winning. (especially since Black can always threaten to pick up the a3 pawn making an immediate draw)

Comment: Did Leela blunder? In a game of 2020 Blitz Computer Championship Leela ( Black) playing Stockfish reached the following position with Black to move FEN 4r3/2P2pk1/1K1Q2p1/4Pb1p/8/6P1/8/8 b. Leela played Re6 and end up losing the game , but my modest Houdini 6.02 do not see a way for White to break through after different Black moves. Was Re6 indeed a blunder , and could Leela still make a draw?